# Google BigQuery - best way to wait for batch query to finish

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, wait, batch-query

I'm using Google BigQuery to run some queries on very large datasets.
As I usually exceed some limits (e.g. query took longer than 6 hours) I want to use batch queries as they don't expect results to be done immediatly.

After the results are available I want to write them to a pandas dataframe and continue from there.
What is the best way, to wait for the results. I tried with `time.sleep`, although it works, there might be a better way.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

key_path = "../path_to_my_credentials.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
)

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=credentials.project_id,)

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    priority=bigquery.QueryPriority.BATCH
)


query = """
SELECT
  name, gender,
  SUM(number) AS total
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013`
GROUP BY
  name, gender
ORDER BY
  total DESC
LIMIT
  10
"""

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

query_job = client.get_job(
    query_job.job_id, location=query_job.location
) 

while(query_job.state != 'DONE'):
    time.sleep(60)
    
df = query_job.to_dataframe()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you’re just missing “result()”

```
client.query(q).result().to_dataframe()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912907/access-token-expired-while-iterating-table-result

Answer (score -1):

Try using the native `add_done_callback` method instead:

For example, with your above query:

```
def set_df(future):
    global df
    df = future.to_dataframe()


query_job = client.query(query=query)
query_job.add_done_callback(set_df)

print(df)
```

This results in the creation of a Dataframe, df, that looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! I will definitely start using `add_done_callback`. Still, I somehow need to "wait" until df is set. Otherwise, I get an error at `print(df)`, cause df is not set yet. How would you do that?

Comment: @Daniel Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73912907/access-token-expired-while-iterating-table-result